# filtering javadoc via annotations

Tags: javadoc

I would like to be able to use @nnotations to mark classes or methods for exclusion from javadoc.

Is there a way to subclass the standard doclet for this purpose? A first pass over the javadoc-doc didn't reveal a solution.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#exclude, http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4058216, http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/05/javadoc-tool-with-exclude-tag.html, http://sixlegs.com/blog/java/exclude-javadoc-tag.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is proposed but not currently implemented the annotation @exclude

In the link you can find a re-implementation of javadoc, with @exclude implemented

http://www.dzone.com/links/javadoc_tool_with_exclude_tag.html

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider using the Doclava doclet:  https://code.google.com/p/doclava/

This implements `@hide` which excludes classes and methods from the resulting javadoc.

It also produces a much more nicely formatted output.  (That said, there are a few things vanilla javadoc does that doclava doesn't, but nothing that I've ever needed.)