# How to create Javadoc HTML pages which includes some tagged classes and class members?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have to create javadoc for my project in which I have to consider the classes only which has the tag "**@accept**" and the class members tagged with "**@ignore**" should not be considered to show in the generated javadoc html page.

Above mentioned has to be done using **JDK8**.

Consider the classes A, B and C given below.

**A.java**

```java
/**
 * @accept
 */
public class A {


    String field1;

    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    String field2;

    public A(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    public A(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    /**
     * @ignore
     */
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}
```

**B.java**

```java
public class B {

    // Fields and methods here...

}
```

C.java

```java
/**
 * @accept
 */
public class C {

    String field1;

    String field2;

    public C(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}
```

When I create javadoc html for the above classes, The output should contain the following.

```
Class A  
- String field1; // field  
- public A(String field1); // constructor  
- public void setField1(String field1); // method  

Class C  
- String field1; // field  
- String field2; // field  
- public C(String field1, String field2); // constructor
```

In the above expected output, We don't see class B as it don't have a tag **@accept**.

For the class A, we Don't entry for the field *field2*, constructor *A(String field1, String field2)* and the method *public void setField2(String field2)* as they hold the tag **@ignore**.

Comment: Have you tried changing the visibility of these fields to private? If I remember rightly, only non-private fields and methods are added to the javadoc.

Comment: @AndreM,
I want the fields and methods to be public so that I can use them in other classes and I don't wanted to expose them out in the javadoc. Hope you are clear with the question.

Comment: Have a look at [filtering javadoc via annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391604/filtering-javadoc-via-annotations). Also [flexdoc](http://www.filigris.com/flexdoc-javadoc/classic/parameters/filter.php#filter.byAnns) seems to be annotation aware.